# Averaging/synchronising spectrograms with slightly different time bases

Tags: python, average, spectrogram

I have a number of spectrograms I wish to average together. There are multiple features in these spectrograms:

Start burst (at 0 ms), BroadBand Fluctuation (BBF) (~9.5 to 13 ms and ~190 to ~220kHz) and end burst(~17 ms), see below for an example:
[Example spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KPRe.png)

I have many of these (one example is 50 spectrgrams to average) and they all have slightly different time axes (since the start burst till end burst duration can vary slightly). More examples:
[Example spectrogram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq0tZ.png)
[Example spectrogram 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLgta.png)

There are a few possible ways to average:

1. Fix everything to start burst, meaning shorter spectrograms finish earlier
2. Normalise the time bases, saying start burst = 0% and end burst = 100%. This means shorter durations are streched while longer ones are squashed.

Both of these have issues though, since method 1 will result in an averaged spectrogram that varies in the number of averaged spectrograms changing as you increase in time. And method 2 may not work since the BBF feature may not scale with increased (or decreased) duration, i.e. BBF lasts ~3ms above, but still lasts ~3ms in a separate spectrogram of start to end burst duration 25ms. Therefore, this could make the averaged spectrogram increasinly cloudy.

I have also thought about plotting all the spectrograms on top of each other, and chaning their opacity. This could work, however I wouldn't have an averaged spectrogram array to perform additional analysis on.

I hope I have made myself clear enough, please ask any questions and I will try respond quickly. Help, answers and solutions are all welcome!

Comment: If it's important to show the "raw data" of the burst(s) then maybe take 3 or so of the "most representative" (or most varied ones, depending what you're trying to argue) and stack them or overlay with an offset. Otherwise, centering them on zero and averaging sounds okay.

Comment: Hi @OriYarden, yes it is important to show the raw data, as there are other (much easier) quantities that I will also be averaging. Therefore, averaging the other quantities (temperature and density) of other spectrograms when not including the respective spectrogram in the "averaged" one is problematic. Centering them around 0 or -3ms sounds like a fine idea, getting the pixel closest to 0 and snapping all the points to the grid sounds like a plausible option. I will update the question and this comment when I have relevant progress. Many thanks Ori Yarden.